# Upload file from react using Axios to API CXF 2.5 java

Tags: java, reactjs, axios, cxf, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a file along some data from a form in react to a server CXF java.

In the react code, i use FormData, a simple axios.post with `multipart/form-data` headers.
In java i tell the webservice to consumme multipart/form-data.

for the text values i want to add to the formData i use the class Blob so that everything is the same, file and text values.

In the webservice java i have as param a `MultivaluedMap<String, String>` and with only text values, i have my data.
If i add the file in the axios post request, i have an error 500 and the server doesnt event log anything, it crashes i think in the mapping with the `MultivaluedMap<String, String>`.

I've tried then to use `MultivaluedMap<Object, Object>` but the problem was the same.

If i use only String as param as expected, i only have the first entry in the data from axios post request and it's the value only not the key.

I wonder if i do something bad on react side but i'm not familiar with CXF so maybe it's my approch on the java side that is bad.

```
    @POST
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public void createInfoCollection(MultivaluedMap<Object, Object> formData) {
        
        try {
            System.out.println("json incoming");
            System.out.println(formData);   
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception = " + e);
        }
    }
```

on react the code is simple and goes as :

```
        const formData = new FormData();

        if (this.state.selectedFile) {
            // Update the formData object 
            formData.append(
                "selectedFile",
                this.state.selectedFile,
                this.state.selectedFile.name
            );
        }

        Object.keys(this.state).map(key => {
            if (key != 'selectedFile') {
                let value = this.state[key];
                const json = JSON.stringify(value);
                const blob = new Blob([json], {
                    type: 'application/json'
                });
                formData.append(key, blob, key);
                // formData.append(key, this.state[key]);
            }
        });

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }
        axios.post("My/Url/That/Works/Well/With/GetRequests", formData, config)
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Thank you

**EDIT** i found out about `MultipartBody` on the java side but i'm still learning how to use this yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found a solution using `MultipartBody formDat`

in this object there are headers `Content-Disposition` that has a property names `name` and a property `filename` if the `Content-Type` is `application/octet-stream`.

If there are other data next to a file it doesnt have any `content-type` but the way to get the name is the same with the property  `name` after parsing the `Content-Disposition`.

Then there are Attachments on the `MultipartBody` and with `attachment.getDataHandler().getInputStream()` i have the content of the file and also the basic values of other data if there are any.

with a match between headers and attachments, i'm guessing i can do whatever i need to do.

Thank you for giving me new inspiration StackOverFlow !